# Downsampling in Pandas DataFrame by dividing observations into ratios

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resampling, pandas-resample

Given a DataFrame having timestamp (ts), I'd like to these by the hour (downsample). Values that were previously indexed by ts should now be divided into ratios based on the number of minutes left in an hour. [note: divide data in ratios for NaN columns while doing resampling]

```
          ts               event  duration
0   2020-09-09 21:01:00 a         12
1   2020-09-10 00:10:00 a         22 
2   2020-09-10 01:31:00 a         130
3   2020-09-10 01:50:00 b         60
4   2020-09-10 01:51:00 b         50
5   2020-09-10 01:59:00 b         26
6   2020-09-10 02:01:00 c         72
7   2020-09-10 02:51:00 b         51
8   2020-09-10 03:01:00 b         63
9   2020-09-10 04:01:00 c         79



def create_dataframe():
    df = pd.DataFrame([{'duration':12, 'event':'a',  'ts':'2020-09-09 21:01:00'},
                         {'duration':22, 'event':'a',  'ts':'2020-09-10 00:10:00'},
                         {'duration':130, 'event':'a', 'ts':'2020-09-10 01:31:00'},
                         {'duration':60, 'event':'b',  'ts':'2020-09-10 01:50:00'},
                         {'duration':50, 'event':'b',  'ts':'2020-09-10 01:51:00'},
                         {'duration':26, 'event':'b',  'ts':'2020-09-10 01:59:00'},
                         {'duration':72, 'event':'c',  'ts':'2020-09-10 02:01:00'},
                         {'duration':51, 'event':'b',  'ts':'2020-09-10 02:51:00'},
                         {'duration':63, 'event':'b',  'ts':'2020-09-10 03:01:00'},
                         {'duration':79, 'event':'c',  'ts':'2020-09-10 04:01:00'},
                         {'duration':179, 'event':'c', 'ts':'2020-09-10 06:05:00'},
                         ])
    df.ts = pd.to_datetime(df.ts)
    return df
```

I want to estimate a produced based on the ratio of time spend and produced. This can be compared to `how many lines of code have been completed or find how many actual lines per hour?`

for example: at "2020-09-10 00:10:00" we have 22. Then during the period from 21:01 - 00:10, we produced based on

```
 59 min of 21:00 hours -> 7   => =ROUND(22/189*59,0)
 60 min of 22:00 hours -> 7   => =ROUND(22/189*60,0)
 60 min of 23:00 hours -> 7   => =ROUND(22/189*60,0)
 10 min of 00:00 hours -> 1   => =ROUND(22/189*10,0)
```

the result should be something like.

```
  ts                  event    duration
0   2020-09-09 20:00:00 a         NaN
1   2020-09-10 21:00:00 a         7
2   2020-09-10 22:00:00 a         7
3   2020-09-10 23:00:00 a         7
4   2020-09-10 00:00:00 a         1
5   2020-09-10 01:00:00 b         ..
6   2020-09-10 02:01:00 c         ..
```

> Problem with this approach:

It appears to me that, we are having a serious issue with this approach. If you look at the rows[1] -> 2020-09-10 07:00:00, we have 4, we need to divide it between 3 hours. Considering base duration value as 1 (base unit), we however get

```
def create_dataframe2():
    df = pd.DataFrame([{'duration':4, 'event':'c', 'c':'event3.5', 'ts':'2020-09-10 07:00:00'},
                        {'duration':4, 'event':'c', 'c':'event3.5', 'ts':'2020-09-10 10:00:00'}])
    df.ts = pd.to_datetime(df.ts)
    return df
```

> Source

```
    duration    event   c   ts
0   4   c   event3.5    2020-09-10 07:00:00
1   4   c   event3.5    2020-09-10 10:00:00
```

> Expected Output

```
    ts_hourly           mins    duration
0   2020-09-10 07:00:00 60.0    2
1   2020-09-10 08:00:00 60.0    1
2   2020-09-10 09:00:00 60.0    1
3   2020-09-10 10:00:00 0.0     0
```

Comment: Your printout of the source DataFrame is inconsistent with the code to create this DataFrame. E.g. in row 3 your code contains *00:31:00* whereas the printout - *01:31:00*.
Another discrepancy is that the code contains *a* and *b* columns, but the printout - *produced* and *event*. Note also that *c* column in the code is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to add "previous ts" column to the source DataFrame:

```
df['tsPrev'] = df.ts.shift()
```

Then set *ts* column as the index:

```
df.set_index('ts', inplace=True)
```

The third step is to create an auxiliary index, composed of the original
index and "full hours":

```
ind = df.event.resample('H').asfreq().index.union(df.index)
```

Then create an auxiliary DataFrame, reindexed with the just created index
and "back fill" *event* column:

```
df2 = df.reindex(ind)
df2.event = df2.event.bfill()
```

Define a function to be applied to each group of rows from *df2*:

```
def parts(grp):
    lstRow = grp.iloc[-1]       # Last row from group
    if pd.isna(lstRow.tsPrev):  # First group
        return pd.Series([lstRow.duration], index=[grp.index[0]], dtype=int)
    # Other groups
    return -pd.Series([0], index=[lstRow.tsPrev]).append(grp.duration)\
        .interpolate(method='index').round().diff(-1)[:-1].astype(int)
```

Then generate the source data for "produced" column in 2 steps:

1. Generate detailed data:

   ```
   prodDet = df2.groupby(np.isfinite(df2.duration.values[::-1]).cumsum()[::-1],
       sort=False).apply(parts).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
   ```

   The source is *df2* grouped this way that each group is terminated
   with a row with a non-null value in *duration* column. Then each group
   is processed with *parts* function.

   The result is:

   ```
   2020-09-09 21:00:00    12
   2020-09-09 21:01:00     7
   2020-09-09 22:00:00     7
   2020-09-09 23:00:00     7
   2020-09-10 00:00:00     1
   2020-09-10 00:10:00    80
   2020-09-10 01:00:00    50
   2020-09-10 01:31:00    60
   2020-09-10 01:50:00    50
   2020-09-10 01:51:00    26
   2020-09-10 01:59:00    36
   2020-09-10 02:00:00    36
   2020-09-10 02:01:00    51
   2020-09-10 02:51:00    57
   2020-09-10 03:00:00     6
   2020-09-10 03:01:00    78
   2020-09-10 04:00:00     1
   2020-09-10 04:01:00    85
   2020-09-10 05:00:00    87
   2020-09-10 06:00:00     7
   dtype: int32
   ```
2. Generate aggregated data, for the time being also as a *Series*:

   ```
   prod = prodDet.resample('H').sum().rename('produced')
   ```

   This time *prodDet* is resampled (broken down by hours) and the
   result is the sum of values.

   The result is:

   ```
   2020-09-09 21:00:00     19
   2020-09-09 22:00:00      7
   2020-09-09 23:00:00      7
   2020-09-10 00:00:00     81
   2020-09-10 01:00:00    222
   2020-09-10 02:00:00    144
   2020-09-10 03:00:00     84
   2020-09-10 04:00:00     86
   2020-09-10 05:00:00     87
   2020-09-10 06:00:00      7
   Freq: H, Name: produced, dtype: int32
   ```

Let's describe the content of *prodDet*:

1. There is no row for *2020-09-09 20:00:00*, because no source row is
   from this hour (your data start from *21:01:00*).
2. Row `21:00:00     12` comes from the first source row (you forgot about
   it writing the expected result).
3. Rows for *21:01:00*, *22:00:00*, *23:00:00* and *00:00:00* come from
   "partitioning" of row `00:10:00 a         22`, just as a part of your
   expected result.
4. Rows with *80* and *50* come from row containing *130*, divided
   between rows with hours *00:01:00* and *01:00:00*.
5. And so on.

Now we start to assemble the final result.

1. Join *prod* (converted to a DataFrame) with *event* column:

   ```
   result = prod.to_frame().join(df2.event)
   ```
2. Add *tsMin* column - the minimal *ts* in each hour (as you asked
   in one of comments):

   ```
   result['tsMin'] = df.duration.resample('H').apply(lambda grp: grp.index.min())
   ```
3. Change the index into a regular column and set its name to *ts*
   (like in the source DataFrame):

   ```
   result = result.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'ts'})
   ```

The final result is:

```
                   ts  produced event               tsMin
0 2020-09-09 21:00:00        19     a 2020-09-09 21:01:00
1 2020-09-09 22:00:00         7     a                 NaT
2 2020-09-09 23:00:00         7     a                 NaT
3 2020-09-10 00:00:00        81     a 2020-09-10 00:10:00
4 2020-09-10 01:00:00       222     a 2020-09-10 01:31:00
5 2020-09-10 02:00:00       144     c 2020-09-10 02:01:00
6 2020-09-10 03:00:00        84     b 2020-09-10 03:01:00
7 2020-09-10 04:00:00        86     c 2020-09-10 04:01:00
8 2020-09-10 05:00:00        87     c                 NaT
9 2020-09-10 06:00:00         7     c 2020-09-10 06:05:00
```

E.g. the value of *81* for *00:00:00* is a sum of *1* and *80* (the first
part resulting from row with *130*), see *prodDet* above.

Some values in *tsMin* column are empty, for hours in which there is no
source row.

If you want to totally drop the result from the first row (with
*duration == 12*), change `return pd.Series([lstRow.duration]...` to
`return pd.Series([0]...` (the 4-th row of *parts* function).

To sum up, my solution is more *pandasonic* and significantly shorter
than yours (17 rows (my solution) vs. about 70 (yours), excluding comments).

Comment: why does not values at 2020-09-10 00:00:00 sum at 81? It should certainly match.

 `3   2020-09-10 00:00:00 10.0    1.0
 0   2020-09-10 00:00:00 50.0    80.0
 1   2020-09-10 01:00:00 31.0    50.0
 0   2020-09-10 01:00:00 19.0    60.0`

Comment: The reason is the discrepancy between your code sample to create *df* and the printout (above it). I pointed it out in a comment to your post.
Your code contains row with *'a':130, 'b':'a', ..., 'ts':'2020-09-10 00:31:00'*
(and I used just this code).
So this source row (with *130*) pertains to activity between *00:10:00*
and *00:31:00* and in my intermediate result it is presented as
*2020-09-10 00:10:00 130*. Start with the *df* created by your **code sample**
and then check details.

Comment: Thanks! @Valdi_Bo. I have changed the DF definition. can you revalidate your answer and update the column name post which I will accept. I am glad for your help in solving this. Also, if you can add mins in all the hours, might help other users!

Comment: I corrected my solution, adding also *tsMin* column (mins in all the hours).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for getting duration in mins in each hour as against what you gave. can you add that as well?

Comment: I realized that column named *duration* is actually not any duration.
Example: Look at rows with times *00:10:00* and *01:31:00*.
The time distance between them is *81* mins, but *duration* in
row with time *01:31:00* is *130*.
So this duration expresses something other than the time distance,
and this DataFrame contains no data about how long did it take to
execute the task pertaining to each row.

Comment: This is sample data, and fields here have no meaning :) I got your code working., I request you to add the `mins` field which has a value of `60` for the first row having a `duration` value as `19` i.e. `(12 + 7)`

Comment: It is still not clear how to compute values for *mins* column.

Comment: I updated the question with a problem in this approach. I found a use case, where rounding Error is changing an interpretation. I agree logic is good but another scenario if fixed could be helpful! 
A solution that I have already added here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65217053/distribute-value-in-buckets

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find a solution in `pandas`, so I created a solution with plain python.

Basically, I am iterating over all the values after sorting and sending two datetimes viz `start_time` and `end_time` to a function, which does the processing.

```
def get_ratio_per_hour(start_time: list, end_time: list, data_: int):

    # get total hours between the start and end, use this for looping
    totalhrs = lambda x: [1 for _ in range(int(x // 3600))
                          ] + [
                             (x % 3600 / 3600 
                              or 0.1 # added for loop fix afterwards
                              )]
              
    
    # check if Start and End are not in same hour
    if start_time.hour != end_time.hour:
        seconds = (end_time - start_time).total_seconds()
        if seconds < 3600:
            parts_ = [1] + totalhrs(seconds)
        else:
            parts_ = totalhrs(seconds)
    else:                       
        # parts_ define the loop iterations
        parts_ = totalhrs((end_time - start_time).total_seconds())
    
    sum_of_hrs = sum(parts_)
    
    # for Constructing DF
    new_hours = []
    mins = []

    # Clone data
    start_time_ = start_time
    end_time_ = end_time

    for e in range(len(parts_)):
        # print(parts_[e])
        if sum_of_hrs != 0:

            
            if sum_of_hrs > 1:
                
                if end_time_.hour != start_time_.hour:

                    # Floor > based on the startTime +1 hour
                    floor_time = (start_time_ + timedelta(hours=1)).floor('H')
    
                    #
                    new_hours.append(start_time_.floor('H'))
                    mins.append((floor_time - start_time_).total_seconds() // 60)
    
                    sum_of_hrs = sum_of_hrs - 1
    
                    start_time_ = floor_time
                
                else:
                    
                    # Hour is same.
                    floor_time = (start_time_ + timedelta(hours=1)).floor('H')
                    new_hours.append(start_time_.floor('H'))
                    mins.append((floor_time - start_time_).total_seconds() // 60)
                    
                    sum_of_hrs = sum_of_hrs - 1

                    start_time_ = floor_time
                    
            else:

                
                if end_time_.hour != start_time_.hour:
                    
                    # Get round off hour
                    floor_time = (end_time_ + timedelta(hours=1)).floor('H')

                    new_hours.append(end_time_.floor('H'))

                    mins.append(60 - ((floor_time - end_time_).total_seconds() // 60)
                                )
                    sum_of_hrs = sum_of_hrs - 1

                    start_time_ = floor_time

                else:

                    # Hour is same.
                    floor_time = (end_time_ + timedelta(hours=1)).floor('H')

                    new_hours.append(end_time_.floor('H'))
                    mins.append((end_time_ - start_time_).total_seconds() // 60)
                    sum_of_hrs = sum_of_hrs - 1

                    start_time_ = floor_time

    # Get DataFrame Build

    df_out = pd.DataFrame()

    df_out['hours'] = pd.Series(new_hours)
    df_out['mins'] = pd.Series(mins)

    df_out['ratios'] = round(data_ / sum(mins) * df_out['mins'])

    return df_out
```

Now, let's run the code for each iteration

```
time_val=[]
split_f_val=[]

split_field = 'duration'
time_field = 'ts'
# creating DataFrames for intermediate results!
df_final = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

for ix, row in df.iterrows():

    time_val.append(row[str(time_field)])
    split_f_val.append(int(row[str(split_field)]))
    
    # Skipping First Element for Processing. Therefore, having minimum two data values
    if ix !=0:
        
        # getting Last Two Values
        new_time_list=time_val[-2:]
        new_data_list=split_f_val[-2:]
        
        # get times to compare
        start_time=new_time_list[: -1][0]
        end_time=new_time_list[1:][0]
        
        # get latest Data to divide
        data_ = new_data_list[1:][0]
        
        # print(start_time)
        # print(end_time)
        df2 = get_ratio_per_hour(start_time,end_time, data_ )   
        df_final = pd.concat([df_final
                              , df2], ignore_index=True)
        
    else:
        
        # Create Empty DataFrame for First Value.
        df_final = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan] ], 
                     columns=['hours', 'mins', 'ratios'])
              
               
        df_final = pd.concat([df_final
                              , df2], ignore_index=True)
                     
    result = df_final.groupby(['hours'])['ratios'].sum()
```

> Intermediate DataFrame:

```
                  hours mins    ratios
0           
0   2020-09-09 21:00:00 59.0    7.0
1   2020-09-09 22:00:00 60.0    7.0
2   2020-09-09 23:00:00 60.0    7.0
3   2020-09-10 00:00:00 10.0    1.0
0   2020-09-10 00:00:00 50.0    80.0
1   2020-09-10 01:00:00 31.0    50.0
0   2020-09-10 01:00:00 19.0    60.0
0   2020-09-10 01:00:00 1.0 50.0
0   2020-09-10 01:00:00 8.0 26.0
0   2020-09-10 01:00:00 1.0 36.0
1   2020-09-10 02:00:00 1.0 36.0
0   2020-09-10 02:00:00 50.0    51.0
0   2020-09-10 02:00:00 9.0 57.0
1   2020-09-10 03:00:00 1.0 6.0
0   2020-09-10 03:00:00 59.0    78.0
1   2020-09-10 04:00:00 1.0 1.0
0   2020-09-10 04:00:00 59.0    85.0
1   2020-09-10 05:00:00 60.0    87.0
2   2020-09-10 06:00:00 5.0 7.0
```

> Final Output:

```
            hours   ratios
2020-09-09 21:00:00 7.0
2020-09-09 22:00:00 7.0
2020-09-09 23:00:00 7.0
2020-09-10 00:00:00 81.0
2020-09-10 01:00:00 222.0
2020-09-10 02:00:00 144.0
2020-09-10 03:00:00 84.0
2020-09-10 04:00:00 86.0
2020-09-10 05:00:00 87.0
2020-09-10 06:00:00 7.0
```