# distribute value in buckets

Tags: python, pandas

Consider below DF, I have an input number=4 to be inserted evenly in different hour buckets.

```
    p_hourly            mins
0   2020-09-10 07:00:00 60.0
1   2020-09-10 08:00:00 60.0
2   2020-09-10 09:00:00 60.0
3   2020-09-10 10:00:00 0.0
```

This means, 4 has to be divided evenly into 4 p_hourly buckets. Let's have `i=1` for each bucket. Now for each iteration, we have to check which `mins` value is highest and add `1` to its specific `i bucket` and divide `mins` by the new `i bucket` value. In case of a row, all `mins` values are the same, we simply take the first one!

I figured out a solution in excel, but need to use python to get this done!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_ratios(df_in, val):
    '''
Dividing into Ratios 
'''
    df_in['x'] = 1
    df_in['new_mins']=df_in.mins
    for i in range(1,val+1):
        
        df_in['new_mins'][df_in.new_mins.idxmax(axis = 0)] = df_in.mins.iloc[df_in.new_mins.idxmax(axis = 0)]/df_in['x'][df_in.new_mins.idxmax(axis = 0)]
        df_in['x'][df_in.new_mins.idxmax(axis = 0)] = df_in['x'][df_in.new_mins.idxmax(axis = 0)] + 1
        
    df_in.x=df_in.x-1

    return df_in.x.values
```